# My SQL Multiple Group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have added a sample Output and expected output below.

```
 SELECT m.Magazine_name,m.MagazineID,m.Publisher_id,l.type,l.production_hour,
    CASE WHEN l.type = '3' THEN SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC(l.production_hour ) ) ) ELSE '00:00:00' END as Production, // Sum of Production Hours
    CASE WHEN l.type = '3' THEN SUM(l.total_images) ELSE '0' END as Production_I,   // Sum of Production Images Count
    CASE WHEN l.type = '6' THEN SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC(l.production_hour ) ) ) ELSE '00:00:00' END as QC, // Sum of QC Hours
    CASE WHEN l.type = '6' THEN SUM(l.total_images) ELSE '0' END as QC_I, // Sum of QC Images Count
    CASE WHEN l.type = '7' THEN SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC(l.production_hour ) ) ) ELSE '00:00:00' END as Amends, // Sum of Amends Hours
    CASE WHEN l.type = '7' THEN SUM(l.total_images) ELSE '0' END as Amends_I, // Sum of Amends Images Count
    from magazine m ,logsheet l where l.magazine = m.MagazineID and m.Publisher_id >= '65' and m.Publisher_id <= '77' and l.date = '2017-04-26'
    group by m.MagazineID,l.type
    union 
    SELECT m.Magazine_name,m.MagazineID,m.Publisher_id,l.type,  l.production_hour,
    CASE WHEN l.type != '3' THEN '00:00:00' ELSE 'COMPLETED' END as Production,
    CASE WHEN l.type != '3' THEN '0' ELSE 'COMPLETED' END as Production_I,
    CASE WHEN l.type != '6' THEN '00:00:00' ELSE 'COMPLETED' END as QC,
    CASE WHEN l.type != '6' THEN '0' ELSE 'COMPLETED' END as QC_I,  
    CASE WHEN l.type != '7' THEN '00:00:00' ELSE 'COMPLETED' END as Amends,
    CASE WHEN l.type != '7' THEN '0' ELSE 'COMPLETED' END as Amends_I,
    from magazine m , logsheet l where  m.Publisher_id >= '65' and m.Publisher_id <= '77' 
    group by m.MagazineID
    ORDER BY 2 ASC
```

Output :

```
| Mag | prod_hour | Image | QC_Hou | QC_ima | Ame_hr | AME_Ima |

| Adidas | 01:02:00 | 08| 00:00:00 | 0 | 00:00:00 | 0 |
| Adidas | 00:00:00 | 0 | 00:15:00 | 05| 00:00:00 | 0 |
| Adidas | 00:00:00 | 0 | 00:00:00 | 0 | 00:30:00 | 04|
| Adidas | 00:00:00 | 0 | 00:00:00 | 0 | 00:00:00 | 0 |
| Puma   | 00:00:00 | 0 | 00:00:00 | 0 | 00:00:00 | 0 |
| Puma   | 00:00:00 | 0 | 01:05:00 | 02| 00:00:00 | 0 |
| Puma   | 01:03:00 | 02| 00:00:00 | 0 | 00:00:00 | 0 |`
```

I'm Displaying my magazines with range of publisher ID's i want to separate the total production hours and Total qc Hours and Total Amends Hours for Each magazines in single row. the row is splitting one by one according to the type.

my type contains what activity they have tracked QC OR production or Amends.

My expected Output is

```
| Mag | prod_hour | Image | QC_Hou | QC_ima | Ame_hr | AME_Ima |

    | Adidas | 01:02:00 | 08| 00:15:00 | 05 | 00:30:00 | 04 |
    | Puma   | 01:03:00 | 02| 01:05:00 | 02 | 00:00:00 | 0 |
```

Please any one help me to sort this out.

Comment: But no input :-(

Comment: I think you want to produce a pivot table. In this case you need to move the conditional statements **within** the aggregate functions and also you need to create the union before you apply a group by.

Comment: Yes, Exactly thanks for the information. now I'm clear on what I'm searching for a pivot table.

Comment: Any One there to help me Out with code to solve this Pivot